# Replace part of string in predefined text container

Tags: jquery, string, replace

I need to replace a hard coded `<br>` inside a given text with a line-break kind of `\n` (not written line-break).

Example:

```
var testText = "Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit<br>amed"
testText.replace("<br>", /\n/g);

$("#MyText").text(testText);
```

Does not work. What am I doing wrong??

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/3bzrf3tj/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#MyText").text(testText);
```

Change this to

```
$("#MyText").html(testText);
```